# Charge transfer in conductors of different metals by touching

Tags: charge, conductors, electrostatic

when we touch two metallic conductors one is neutral and other has excess of charges,
Case 1- Both metals are of copper, then we can calculate actual charges on them at steady state by capacitance formula Case 2- One metal are of copper and other of aluminium, and again we can calculate steady state charges by capacitance formula

Problem- If size and shape of conductors remain same then calculated charge on both cases will also be same because capacitance depends on size and shape but intuitively why this can be true? Even changing metals doesn't change anything about charge transfer which seems quite counterintuitive to me or I'm missing something? And does time constants (charging time) in both cases will change or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by capacitance formula ? Can you post it here ? In that formula, the conductors are assumed to be perfect (hence independent of the type of metal) and charging time doesn't come into picture. The charges are transferred instantly.

Comment: Capacitance formula i.e formula for self capacitance of conductor and then we can use v=q/c to equate potential of both conductor (after they touch each other) and we can obtain charge on both conductors, but as you said if conductors are assumed to be independent, but is there any mathematical formula to exactly determine transient charge at any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge transfer accompanying bringing into contact (and then possible separation) of two metallic bodies is a multifaceted physical phenomenon. John Lekner studied a process of equalization of galvani potentials and published a notable research in Proc. of the Royal Society A, '[Electrostatics of two charged conducting spheres](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2012.0133)'.
If the bodies are made of different metals, bringing these into contact equalizes their electrochemical potentials (fermi levels), see Steve Byrnes' answer to a question in physics SE '[Fermi level alignment and electrochemical potential between two metals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70341/fermi-level-alignment-and-electrochemical-potential-between-two-metals)'.

Anyway, to calculate time dependent transient currents of the charge transfer process [in order to determine "time constants (charging time) in both cases"], you need to solve a PDE system with parameters and boundary/initial conditions specific for geometries and physical properties of the bodies you study.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful, can you suggest some books or any platform where i can get boundary value problems similar to this problem 3

Comment: If you are a student interested in numerical calculations, you can take a course on partial differential equations with applications to electromagnetic problems and materials studies in an engineering school of your choice. If you are in electronics or materials engineering, search for articles on "charge relaxation" and "contact electrification" published in journals like Phys. Rev. E, European Journal Of Physics, IEEE Trans. On Industrial App., etc. Good Luck!